# Tap gesture does not get called if my view background color is clearColor only on iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, uitapgesturerecognizer

Tap gesture does not get called if my view background color is clearColor.

I also tried a button with background clear color, the action does not get called.

Comment: Manually set `setUserInteractionEnabled:YES` on the view?

Comment: i tried it but it does not work

Comment: once i change the color have .1 opacity it start working fine

Comment: I also found this to be a problem using iOS 8.2 and Swift in Xcode 6.2. Setting the alpha to 0.1 also worked for me where I used `UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1)`.